# stdlib content unavailable with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, std, codeblocks

I just passed my current project (on Code::Blocks | MinGW | GCC) from C++ to C++11.
So I added "-std=c++11" in the compiler settings.

But now it seems that **i can't access stdlib.h content** such as MAX_PATH or atoi(). These are "not declared".

After some researches i tried adding "-std=libc++" on both compiler and linker settings, without success...

I usually don't modify the compiler options and i'm quite lost when i have to...

*So my questions are:*

- Does c++11 change the stdlib file linked ?
- How can i get {MAX_PATH, atoi, ...} now?

Comment: Assuming you mean `PATH_MAX`, it is not part of the C standard library.

Comment: Just FYI. You should use cstdlib insted of stdlib.h in all C++ projects. stdlib.h i legacy C header file.

Answer (score 0):

1. To use functions like `atoi()` you need to include [`<cstdlib>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) instead of `<stdlib.h>`
2. To get `MAX_PATH`, you need to include [`<climits>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) for Windows. For a Linux systsem, you need to include `<linux/limits.h>`

Comment: I found MAX_PATH in <windows.h> but not in <climits>; but <cstdlib> was what i was looking for, thanks you